# Are there medications that treat premature ejaculation without interfering in serotonin levels?

Tags: medications, mechanism-of-action, pharmacokinetics

The widespread medications that are being used to treat premature ejaculation (PE) are kind of antidepressants called SSRIs (Selective Serotonin Reuptake Inhibitors). But the problem with this kind of medications is that they increase serotonin levels in blood and this can negatively affect one's libido in the long-term.

My question is that are there any medications (oral tablets) that treat premature ejaculation without interfering in serotonin levels in order to remain sexual desire high all the time?

My researches:

According to [this](https://www.mayoclinic.org/diseases-conditions/depression/in-depth/ssris/art-20044825#:%7E:text=How%20SSRIs%20work,reuptake%20of%20serotonin%20into%20neurons.) website:

> SSRIs treat depression by increasing levels of serotonin in the brain.

Also, from [this](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2374931/#:%7E:text=The%20SSRIs%20block%205%2DHT,(Olivier%20et%20al%201998).) site:

> The SSRIs block 5-HT reuptake, and these results in an increased 5-HT neurotransmission and activation of post-synaptic 5-HT receptors. SSRI-induced delayed ejaculation and anorgasmia is probably related to an increased central 5-HT (5-hydroxytriptamine) neurotransmission and activation of postsynaptic 5-HT receptors.

And, finally, according to [this](https://www.mhanational.org/what-serotonin#:%7E:text=High%20levels%20of%20serotonin%20tend,in%20the%20brain%20are%20activated.) site:

> High levels of serotonin tend to indicate a low libido, while low levels of serotonin correspond with a high libido—but that's not the whole story. Technically, whether serotonin inhibits or stimulates your libido depends on which receptors in the brain are activated.

Comment: Related: [Anorgasmia with SSRI and SNRI prescriptions](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/q/11729/7951)